# Regex - skip over expressions and parse the rest

Tags: regex, perl

I use regular expressions for sorting data into groups. The lines look somewhat like:

```
    testword test 
    test testword
    tes.w. tes.
    tes tes.w.
    tes.w othertexttobefound
    sometexttobefound testword somemoretextwhichdoesnotmatter
```

The word `test` is to be found as well as `othertexttobefound` and `sometexttobefound`.

Now I am trying to tell my parser that it is supposed to plainly ignore `testword` and its derivatives while searching and focus on the rest of my data entries. The "good words" and the "bad words" can be anywhere in each line.

I have tried `[^w]` which is fine for the beginning of strings, but in my versions not for the other cases. Also `(?:w)` didn't do the trick. I cannot use lookarounds as these would keep the whole line from being detected.

After long searches on the internet I am hoping for help here!

After much appreciated help from Naxos84, I am adding some German real life examples:

```
sozialabgabe sozialarbeiter
soz.abg. sozialarbeiter
sozarbeiter soz.abg.
sozialarbeiter otherirrelevantstuff
otherirrelevantstuff soz abg
otherirrelevantstuff sozabg
otherirrelevantstuff sozialabgabe
```

If I search with:

```
sozial["^\ab"]|soz["^\ab"]|sometexttobefound|othertexttobefound
```

Lines 6 and 7 get marked as well, but I don't want those.

What am I doing wrong?

A link:
[regexr](http://regexr.com/3gu9a)

Comment: Are you talking about a Perl program or the PCRE Perl regex engine?

Comment: To match whole words, use `\b` for word boundaries. Example: `/\btest\b/` will match "test" but not "testword" or "wordtest" or "wordtestword". Word boundaries may occur at the beginning and end of lines.

Comment: @simbabque, There's no such thing as a "PCRE Perl regex engine". I think you meant "PCRE regex engine".

Comment: @ikegami I did. Not sure where that extra word came from.

Comment: I use regex in SAS. I only know that it seems to be based on Perl, but the details are out of my reach.

Comment: I just edited the question by adding real life words and a link.

Answer (score 0):

To find all the matches you want: any occurence of "test" and "sometexttobefound" and "othertexttobefound you can try the following regex:

```
test[^\w]|sometexttobefound|othertexttobefound
```

This regex means:
Find every "test" that is **not** followed by a word OR sometexttobefound OR othertexttobefound

I tried this regex with the follow text (I added a few 'test's)

```
testword test 
test testword
tes.w. testtes.
tes tes.w. test
tes.w othertexttobefound
sometexttobefound testword somemoretextwhichdoesnotmatter
```

at [regexr](https://regexr.com/3gtvi) (when using the global flag)

If you also want to find things like "tes" I guess you should add it. (I'm not a regex expert)
Like:

```
test[^\w]|tes[^\w]|sometexttobefound|othertexttobefound
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is a comment or an attempt to answer. If it's an answer, please [edit] and make it more clear. You might also want to include a permalink to regexr where you have set up the pattern already for convenience.

Comment: @simbabque I tried to make it more clear. apperently I cannot share a link with the content that is shown in the picture.

Comment: There's a _share_ link at the top right in the blue bar. Doesn't that do it?

Comment: @simbabque I found a way to share a perma link.

Comment: Thank you. However, how can I also find derivatives of `test` (such as `tes`), such as the first in line 4. If I now write `tes[^w]`it will not find `test`. If I write `tes.?[^w]`it will find everything.

Comment: use "\w" instead of just "w" cause "\w" is the character class for "word" and "w" is just the letter. I also extended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all words from the text except from some special words, you could use:

```perl
@words = grep{$_ ne 'testword'} split /\P{L}+/, $str;
```

(if `$str` is your complete string)

See [perl docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops#Properties-accessible-through-%5Cp%7B%7D-and-%5CP%7B%7D) for `\P{...}`. Instead of `\P{L}`, you could also use `\W`, but those are locale-dependent.

But if you need to use regexps only, then you could use

```perl
@words = $str =~ /\b(?!testword)\p{L}+\b/g;
```

But again, `\b` is locale-dependent again, so you might want to use [`\b{...}`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Assertions) or rebuild the word boundary matches with `\p{L}`:

```perl
@words = $str =~ /
  (?:(?<=\p{L})(?!\p{L})|(?<!\p{L})(?=\p{L}))
  (?!testword)\p{L}+
  (?:(?<=\p{L})(?!\p{L})|(?<!\p{L})(?=\p{L}))
/gx;
```